# MPI_Init equivalent to MPI_Init_thread with MPI_THREAD_SINGLE?

Tags: mpi

Is `MPI_Init` equivalent to `MPI_Init_thread` with `desired = MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`?

PS. There are plenty of questions on `MPI_Init` vs `MPI_Init_thread` here (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851903/mpi-init-vs-mpi-init-thread)) but they don't mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard states this explicitly:

> A call to MPI_INIT has the same effect as a call to MPI_INIT_THREAD
> with a required = MPI_THREAD_SINGLE.